# Recursive function involving class

Tags: python, class, recursion, set

```
def check_classes(cls):
    if len(cls.__bases__) == 0:
        return []
    else:
        test_list = []
        for x in range(len(cls.__bases__)):
            test_list += [cls] + check_classes(cls.__bases__[x])
        for x in cls.__bases__:
            return test_list + [x]
```

I currently have a recursive function that takes a class as its parameter and returns a list of all base classes.  This works fine, but it has many duplicate classes in the list.  I want to return a set instead of a list and was wondering how I could go about changing the code to do so.

Comment: If you want to return a `set`, why don't you just use a `set`?

Comment: use 'return set(test_list + [x])'

Comment: Why use this **at all** and not `class.__mro__`?

Comment: Don't vanadalize your posts. I have rollbacked to previous sane version.

Answer (score 3):

Python has a builtin `set` type that eliminates duplicates:

```
def get_bases(obj):
   bases = {obj}  # new set including only obj
   if not(obj.__bases__):  # technically redundant - iter is a noop on empty collections
      return bases
   else:
      for x in obj.__bases__:
          bases.update(get_bases(x))  # update set - automatically eliminates duplicates
      return bases
```

This code already avoids adding many duplicates in the first place. However, the `set` still eliminates duplicates in case of multiple inheritance.

```
class A: ...
class B1(A): ...
class B2(A): ...
class C(B1, B2): ...
print(get_bases(C))
# {<class '__main__.C'>, <class '__main__.B1'>, <class 'object'>, <class '__main__.B2'>, <class '__main__.A'>}
```

---

Python being Python, there is already something that does this:

```
>>> C.__mro__
(__main__.C, __main__.B1, __main__.B2, __main__.A, object)
```

If you just care about the bases, use `__mro__`. Its order also expresses how lookup is performed with multiple bases.

---

A slightly different approach for such searches is to use a `set` to *track* duplicates, but a `list` to *store* elements:

```
def get_bases(obj, _dupes=None):
   _dupes = _dupes if _dupes is not None else set()
   bases = [obj]  # new list including only obj
   _dupes.add(obj)
   for x in obj.__bases__:
       if x not in _dupes:
           bases.extend(get_bases(x, _dupes))  # update set - automatically eliminates duplicates
   return bases
```

This uses a `_dupes: set` to check whether you already visited a class. Instead of eliminating classes you added twice, it only adds them once in the first place. A `set` is faster for this check than a `list`, given many elements. However, you need the `list` to preserve order.

Answer (score 2):

Your function is redundant in that it can be replaced with [`cls.__mro__`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#class.__mro__):

```
>>> class Base: pass
...
>>> class Foo(Base): pass
...
>>> class Bar(Base): pass
...
>>> class Baz(Foo, Bar): pass
...

>>> Baz.__mro__
(<class '__main__.Baz'>, <class '__main__.Foo'>, <class '__main__.Bar'>, <class '__main__.Base'>, <class 'object'>)
```

Your biggest issue is that your implementation adds classes to the list *twice*, once in the recursive call, then again in the current call. Only add the *current* class to the list. Checking for the `__bases__` list as empty is redundant too, as the `for` loop already not do anything if the sequence is empty.

So this is enough:

```
def check_classes(cls):
    result = [cls]
    for base in cls.__bases__:
        result += check_classes(base)
    return result
```

But this will still repeat base classes that have been included in the hierarchy more than once:

```
>>> check_classes(Baz)
[<class '__main__.Baz'>, <class '__main__.Foo'>, <class '__main__.Base'>, <class 'object'>, <class '__main__.Bar'>, <class '__main__.Base'>, <class 'object'>]
```

Note that `Base` and `object` appear twice, due to multiple inheritance. You could use a set to avoid this:

```
def check_classes(cls):
    result = set([cls])
    for base in cls.__bases__:
        result.update(check_classes(base))
    return result
```

at which point we lose ordering, but that may be sufficient for your needs:

```
>>> check_classes(Baz)
{<class '__main__.Bar'>, <class '__main__.Foo'>, <class '__main__.Base'>, <class 'object'>, <class '__main__.Baz'>}
```

However, then you could just use `set(cls.__mro__)` and be done with it:

```
>>> check_classes(Baz) == set(Baz.__mro__)
True
```